# Basic Authentication over redirection

Tags: c#, redirect, http-headers, httpwebrequest

I have a webservice that needs a Basic Authentication header. However, when I call it using

```
   var header = "Authorization: Basic " + 
                CreateBasicHttpAuthenticationHeader(login, password);
   webRequest.Headers.Add(header);
   var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
```

It returns a 303 - See Other:

```
POST https://myservice/rates HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic QXZ...NjY=
Content-Type: application/x-content
X-API-Version: 1.1
If-Unmodified-Since: Mon, 23 Sep 2013 08:32:27 GMT
User-Agent: UserAgent
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 303 See Other
Date: Mon, 23 Sep 2013 08:30:57 GMT
X-Opaque-ID: q8nxxxxc
Location: https://myservice/rates 
Content-Length: 0
```

.Net then automatically sends a GET request to the new location:

```
GET https://myservice/rates HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-content
X-API-Version: 1.1
If-Unmodified-Since: Mon, 23 Sep 2013 08:32:27 GMT
User-Agent: UserAgent
```

But does not send the Authorization header this time. Do you know a way to tell it to send all headers, on all calls? Should I tell it not to follow the content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to deactivate the `AllowRedirect` property of your HttpRequest.

Then you have to build you own redirection system with basic auth headers.

This is not wonderful, but otherwise the .Net framework drops your header when redirecting.