# 401 Unauthorized when calling Stormpath REST API with WebRequest object?

Tags: c#, basic-authentication, stormpath

I am using Stormpath for my authentication service. I call the RestAPI of Stormpath by using HttpWebRequest.

I am also using HttpWebRequest to call the RestAPI but it does not work.

```
private void BtnGetResetApiClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

var username = "aaaa";
var password = "bbbb";
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = Callback;
var request = WebRequest.Create("https://api.stormpath.com/v1/tenants/current") as HttpWebRequest;

request.UserAgent = ".NET SDK";
request.Method = "GET";
request.Accept = "*/*";

var data = string.Format("{0}:{1}", username, HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(password));

var token = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));
string authHeader = string.Format("Basic {0}", token);

request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader);
request.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = Callback;

using (var response = request.GetResponse())
{
    var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
    if (stream != null)
    {
        var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
        var str = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        streamReader.Close();
        stream.Close();
    }
  }
}

private bool Callback(object obj, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain  chain, SslPolicyErrors errors)
{
 return true;
}
```

When calling:

```
var response = request.GetResponse()
```

I got an exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

Can you help me to see if my code has something wrong?

Comment: You need to tell us what happens, how it goes wrong (error message? no answer?...), what you expect,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update - use the SDK, it's much easier!

If you're calling the Stormpath API from C# frequently, don't bother with writing requests by hand. Use the [Stormpath .NET SDK](https://docs.stormpath.com/csharp/product-guide/latest/quickstart.html) instead. I'm the author. :)

Install it using `install-package Stormpath.SDK` from the Package Manager Console. Then, create an `IClient` object:

```
// In a production environment, you'll want to load these from
// environment variables or a secure file, instead of hardcoding!
var apiKey = ClientApiKeys.Builder()
                 .SetId("Your_Stormpath_API_key_ID")
                 .SetSecret("Your_Stormpath_API_key_secret")
                 .Build();
var client = Clients.Builder()
                 .SetApiKey(apiKey)
                 .Build();
```

Getting the tenant info is now just a simple call:

```
var tenant = await client.GetCurrentTenantAsync();
Console.WriteLine($"Current tenant is: {tenant.Name}");
```

If you really want to make raw requests, you can still do that! I'll explain below.

---

#### Constructing the Authorization header

A `401 Unauthorized` response means that the API was not able to find a valid Authorization header in your request. To authenticate correctly, you need two things:

- An authorization payload in the format `apiKeyID:apiKeySecret`
- An `Authorization` header with value: `Basic base64(payload)`

Here's how to construct the complete header:

```
// API_KEY_ID and API_KEY_SECRET populated elsewhere
var authPayload = string.Format("{0}:{1}", API_KEY_ID, API_KEY_SECRET);
var authPayloadEncoded = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(authPayload));
request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Basic " + authPayloadEncoded);
```

You don't need the `ServerCertificateValidationCallback = Callback` stuff. With the above header, the request will be seen by the API as a valid request (assuming your API Key ID and Secret are correct, of course).

---

#### Redirection handling

One thing to watch out for (this tripped me up at first!) is that WebRequest will follow HTTP 302 redirects automatically, but [will **not** apply the existing headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18955476/basic-authentication-over-redirection) to the new request.

The solution is to disable redirect following:

```
request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
```

This means you'll have to handle 302 responses yourself, but it's the only way to correctly apply the Authorization header to each request.

---

#### Working example

I created a simple working example in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/nbarbettini/6e1c21367d88dd6ce538). Since I'll be creating requests multiple times, I wrote a helper function:

```
private static HttpWebRequest BuildRequest(string method, string uri)
{
    var request = WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
    request.UserAgent = "dotnet/csharp web-request";
    request.Method = method;
    request.ContentType = "application/json";

    // Important, otherwise the WebRequest will try to auto-follow
    // 302 redirects without applying the authorization header to the
    // subsequent requests.
    request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

    // Construct HTTP Basic authorization header
    var authPayload = string.Format("{0}:{1}", API_KEY_ID, API_KEY_SECRET);
    var authPayloadEncoded = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(authPayload));
    request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Basic " + authPayloadEncoded);

    return request;
}
```

And a simple console app to demonstrate getting the current tenant URL and name:

```
// Get these from the Stormpath admin console
private static string API_KEY_ID = "Your_Stormpath_API_key_ID";
private static string API_KEY_SECRET = "Your_Stormpath_API_key_secret";

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // First, we need to get the current tenant's actual URL
    string tenantUrl = null;
    var getCurrentTenantRequest = BuildRequest("GET", "https://api.stormpath.com/v1/tenants/current");

    try
    {
        using (var response = getCurrentTenantRequest.GetResponse())
        {
            tenantUrl = response.Headers["Location"];
        }
    }
    catch (WebException wex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Request failed. {0}", wex.Message);
        throw;
    }

    // Now that we have the real tenant URL, get the tenant info
    string tenantData = null;
    var getTenantInfoRequest = BuildRequest("GET", tenantUrl);

    try
    {
        using (var response = getTenantInfoRequest.GetResponse())
        using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        {
            tenantData = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
    catch (WebException wex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Request failed. {0}", wex.Message);
        throw;
    }

    // Use JSON.NET to parse the data and get the tenant name
    var parsedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(tenantData);
    Console.WriteLine("Current tenant is: {0}", parsedData["name"]);

    // Wait for user input
    Console.ReadKey(false);
}
```

The code is pretty verbose because we're making raw requests to the API. Again, if you're making requests frequently, use the SDK instead!